# Best way to rewrite modern browsers to modern version of app?

Tags: redirect

I have a Flash app at `URL-A`. I have a new non Flash version, that only works in modern browsers at `URL-B`. I can redirect all visitors from `URL-A` to `URL-B` with `.htaccess` or `PHP` but I wont know what browser they have in order to determine if I need to redirect or not.

So I am not sure what the best way to go about this is.

Basically if you are using IE8+, FF, Chrome, Safar, Opera I want you to go to `URL-B`. If you are using `IE7-` I want you to go to `URL-A`

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you use a server side language?

Comment: @Pekka Yes PHP. But I dont think there is anyway to determine their browser on the server-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no problem with using a small PHP library, look at the answer to [this question](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/) and do a `header("Location:url")` redirect depending on which result you get.

If you'd rather use a `.htaccess` file, you could parse the USER_AGENT as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent) (it's aimed at mobile browsers but doesn't really matter). The PHP solution is much more convenient though.