# How to rewrite to mobile.myUrl.com if user is mobile? (use Apache or inside Webapp?)

Tags: apache, mobile, url-rewriting

If a user is viewing my Website www.myUrl.com with a mobile Browser, I would like to redirect them to mobile.myUrl.com.
I read this thread [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent), which says, that you should detect the user-agent and then redirect the user.

But I havent found a thread, which tells me HOW to redirect to mobile.myUrl.com. Should and can I use Apache for that? Or should I instead do it inside my Webapp?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent), use apache rewrite **Or** equivalent of rewrite in IIS

Comment: @ajreal: The OP has read that, as posted.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski - That answer has included apache rewrite, I don't see any reason to repeat the same question again

Comment: @ajreal: The OP wanted an opinion on whether he should use Apache or "do it inside my webapp." It is similar, but certainly not a duplicate.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski - does not 14 upvotes explain everything?

Comment: @ajreal: Yes, it does. However, the OP had a thought conflict: "Should and can I use Apache for that? Or should I instead do it inside my Webapp?" This poses another issue.

Comment: Evan Mulawski gave me exactly the answer I wanted: 1.) He showed me how to redirect inside my Webapp with Javascript and 2.) He showed me how to redirect to my subdomain mobile.myUrl.com with Apache. 
I havent found these answers anywhere else yet. So why am I being downvoted???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JAVASCRIPT**

First, let me point out that most mobile devices have the ability to disable Javascript.

Now, the most common form of redirection for mobile devices is through Javascript. (Apple's website uses this method.) When the page begins to load, a script is run to determine the User Agent, a browser-specific (and os-specific) string that details the browser type, device type, and/or operating system. This string is then matched against known mobile devices. For example:

```
<script language=javascript>
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)))
{
   location.replace("http://mobile.myurl.com");
}
-->
</script>
```

This script would redirect any browser with a user agent containing "iPhone" or "iPod" to "mobile.myurl.com".

This would need to be checked for a bunch of other devices.

Check this site for more information:

http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-javascript.htm

If you are using a PHP-compatible server, see this site:

http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-php.htm

**APACHE**

Simply using the mod_rewrite engine, you can redirect browsers with specific user agent strings, just like the Javascript method above:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPod
RewriteRule .* http://mobile.myurl.com/ [R]
```

This checks for "iPhone" and "iPod" users and redirects them to a mobile version of the site.

More here:

http://www.themepremium.com/htaccess-code-http_user_agent-of-multiple-phone-browsers-for-wordpress-blogs/

Comment: Use apache rewrite is clean-cut and more efficient

Comment: @ajreal: I have added an apache method.

Comment: you can combine both rewrite, extra rule extra overhead