# Htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to rewrite to mobile.myUrl.com if user is mobile? (use Apache or inside Webapp?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483180/how-to-rewrite-to-mobile-myurl-com-if-user-is-mobile-use-apache-or-inside-webap)

Hi there! I'm trying to write a rewrite rule, that would redirect every address in my domain, to index.php, like this:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule .* /index.php`

The problem with this code is that in index.php I check whether user came to my website from a pc, or a mobile device, and according to that I redirect him to appropriate version (index.html, or mobi.html) - now since this rule applies I'm stuck in a redirection loop. Pls help stackoverflowers :).

Comment: This would be more elegantly solvable in a server side language like PHP, because you will have to maintain a list of user agents that is likely to grow over time. E.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117555/simplest-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device

Comment: But I know how to detect mobile device - and I'm doing it in php. I use this rewrite condition because of situation like this: www.my-web-site.com/atricle/id <- is need to capture /article/id, so that my app won't follow this url.

Comment: what does that have to do with detecting movile devices then? I don't understand.

Comment: Nothing - I just gave an example for my usage case of this. In sum: I want to redirect every address in my domain to index.php, but when I'm doing this (from inside of index.php in m _domain): header('Location: mydomain.com/index.html'); I don't want this rule to apply - is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you just exclude the pages index.html and mobi.html:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/mobi.html
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

or you can set a GET variable in your redirected url, like `header('Location: domain.com/index.html?norewrite');` and then do not rewrite the URL if it contains this variable:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?norewrite(&.*)?$
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```