# Simple way to check whether user is mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to create a simple redirect on my homepage for users of major mobile OS (at least Android, Nokia/Symbian, Windows, iOS and Blackberry OS).

At present I have it working for iPhone / iPod (see below), but I'm wondering whether there's a simple way in javascript to check for all. (As opposed to just writing out a big ol list of mobile userAgents).

Perhaps something that detects screensize?

```
// Current Code
<script type="text/javascript">
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == -1) {
        window.location = "http://m.domain.co.nz";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

Comment: I'm not writing this as an answer, but you might find this usefull: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/

Answer (score 1):

This properly done on the server, not on the client.