# Redirecting mobile devices without using a sub-domain

Tags: php, html, css

I'm interested in building a mobile site and have done some research on the subject. Everywhere I've looked contains information on either changing CSS upon detecting a mobile device, or setting up a sub-domain to redirect mobile browsers to.

My questions is: can I redirect mobile browsers to a different HTML page without having create a sub-domain? I'm thinking that it may be possible to do with a php page located alongside my HTML, CSS, etc. but I don't know that much about PHP (I'm currently learning the language now).

Answer (score 3):

Redirecting to a subdomain is only used to keep everything organized.

It's easier to keep everything separate if you have a separate view running. It will be the same site, just that the view it is serving is mobile friendly. So you could have `site.com/page` as your normal site, and `site.com/page_mobile` as you mobile *if you wanted*, but this isn't recommended.

Much better to have a subdomain/site or at least a separate folder `site.com/mobile/page`. This pattern will just give you a lot of flexibility when working with multiple sites

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] value of php to detect if request coming from a mobile browser. Then you can redirect user to a simple www.yoursite.com/mobile.php file by php header function.

Your question has solutions on [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent) question.