# How detect browser with .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, wap, wml

I want detect user browsers with .htaccess & redirect when user does not entered the site from cell phone

Comment: @SalmanPK, it is not duplicate

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent

Comment: @SalmanPK, but I want do it with .htaccess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3374559.htm) with an example.

```
# Rewrite requests from all user-agents except modern Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^Mozilla/4\.[0-9]+\ \(compatible;\ MSIE\ [0-9.]+
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^Mozilla/5\.0 \(([^;]+;\ )*[^;]+\)\ Gecko/2[0-9]{3}\ Firefox/[0-9.]+
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^Opera/[0-9.]+
RewriteRule .* X.html [L]
```

Adjust as necessary.