# web framework support both desktop & mobile web browser?

Tags: web-applications, web-frameworks, mobile-browser

I want to make an application which can automatically detect & load different UIs for the desktop browser and mobile browser.

I'm looking for some easy and automatic way to do it. I wonder if there exist any web application framework which support this feature for their pre-defined UI widget? So that I can just focus on the functionality of the website and forget the cross-platform stuff.

all platforms and languages are okie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring-MVC, especially with the [spring-mobile](http://www.springsource.org/spring-mobile) extension can do that. It's Java (You didn't specify language or platform), and perhaps it will be usable with groovy/grails.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this very popular question: [Auto-detect mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)