# Problem on redirecting website for either mobile or desktop version?

Tags: css, html, windows-mobile, user-agent

Hey i have made **both the desktop version and the mobile version of a website**.so now when a visitor visit my website then **how do i came to know that this visitor to my website using a mobile phone or PC?**

To be more clear,when a visitor **visit through mobile** then it should **redirect the visitor to the mobile version of my website** and if **through desktop** then **redirect to the desktop version of website**?
How can I do that?I am using HTML5 and CSS for ma website?

Any help is appreciated?

UPDATE--> What if i want to get the answer through the **USER AGENT**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript navigator object to retrieve user-agent string. (Only problem with this approach is you will have to keep updating list of mobile device useragents every time a new device is invented.) Following question discusses detection of mobile browser using user-agents. [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/) contains some tricks involving the size of the screen and User Agent matches that could be used.

Comment: if we wrote for both mobile as well as desktop so will it work or not
?

Comment: The idea is that you can put that detection code on the 'normal' page and redirect to a mobile-specific page if a mobile device is detected.    Else you allow the current page to be rendered fully.  Better is to use server-side scripting, like PHP.

Comment: hey what about to get through the USER AGENT?how to do that?

Comment: here it is specifically mentioned for iphone and ipad why?as iphone also has width<600

Answer (score 0):

@Geetanjali; you have define `device-width` & `meta` tag in your html like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media"screen and (max-device-width: 400px)" href="mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media"screen" href="main.css">
```

So, when user open your website in mobile then it's call `mobile.css` & it's overwrite main.css the properties for for your mobile website.

read these article for more http://x7.fi/2010/02/12/how-to-fit-your-website-for-the-apple-ipad/ , http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 main approaches you can take:

1. **Subdomain** (m.domain.com is standard). Separate views optimized for the mobile devices you support. Best to always provide a
   link from the mobile site to the "full" site. You can also cookie
   folks for their preference.
2. **Device Detection** This can range from heavy duty like
   [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) to something simpler that
   does device detection (usually on user agent strings). Again provide the user with a link to the "full" site and cookie preferences.
3. **Responsive Design** Use a fluid grid and [media
   queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to create a
   [Responsive
   Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/)
   that provides a good experience for all clients.

Of the 3 approaches, I think Responsive Design makes the most sense these days unless you need to support feature phones, then a combination of m.domain.com and Responsive Design.