# Web content that's conditional on the BlackBerry model number

Tags: blackberry, mobile, media-queries

I have a responsive site that I'm developing where I'm using a image slider as the header that works great and responds great in Android, iPhone with both vertical and landscape views. According to an online testing simulator; it even renders great in Blackberry Torch. HOWEVER, in Blackberry Curve - the image slider seems to break the layout.

Is there any way or any such thing as a code that will detect which device I'm using and hide an element accordingly? Like a BlackBerry Curve conditional statement / media query something?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check the user-agent string sent up by the phones browser to identify the handset model and return the most appropriate HTML.

For the format of the string please see: [How to detect the BlackBerry Browser](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-detect-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/559862).

Please also see [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent) as to how you may use the user-agent in a conditional statement/configuration in many platforms/languages.

I think media queries support came in BB OS5 and the phone you mentioned (Curve, depending on the model) can have an earlier OS version. Also I don't think any media queries exist that will distinguish based on a phones model number.