# is there any way to check the information of client device in javascript or php, which request to server? is this device mobile, tablet or pc?

Tags: php, javascript

I need to detects client device at server end using php or javascript?
which is client device and which browser is using that device?

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/php-mobile-device-detect/246397 buy and enjoy, otherwise post what you have done so far.

Answer (score 2):

Look into examining the `User-Agent` header.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `$_SERVER` with `HTTP_USER_AGENT` http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.useful.php

[Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

What is a user-agent? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Answer (score 0):

Check out Tera-WURFL (http://dbapi.scientiamobile.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It's an API that detects the capabilities of mobile devices. We use it here to determine whether to forward a user to desktop or mobile version of our applications.