# detect mobile phone by web server

Tags: android, iphone, webserver, mobile-website

I would like to know what field within the http packet which was sent by client browser to WEB server can i look to detect whether the request was made from mobile device or from a PC.

My web server is open source which uses C programming language and runs a TCP socket and listens on HTTP port.

Can anyone please let me know.

Comment: your question looks like asked before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to see for HTTP header called "User-Agent". The value of this will help you determine where the request was made from.

For further details you can check this answer: [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent/1005171#1005171)