# What is the best way to do a mobile redirect?

Tags: css, mobile, redirect, web

I'm sure this gets asked a lot, but I also know things change quite frequently, so I am wondering what the current best way to do a simple mobile detection and redirection for a site is.

I'm not going to be able to cover all phones, but I'd like to at least get iphones and androids.

Thanks

Comment: "Best" might be too subjective. Can you talk about the technology you are using?

Comment: These posts might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176037/standard-practices-in-detecting-mobile-devices-and-feeding-pages-in-php-and-jque

Comment: I googled "htaccess detect mobile browser" and got some promising hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkBrowser(){
        var str=navigator.appVersion; 
        var patt1=/Android/;
        var patt2=/iPhone/;
        if(str.match(patt1) || str.match(patt2)){
            window.location="http://m.yoursite.com";
        }
    }
</script>
```

then on the body-tag put onload="checkBrowser();"

it's a very simple way to do it, but i'm sure there plenty more ways..
hope it helps :)