# Making a custom wordpress theme mobile friendly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to do a mobile redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300480/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-mobile-redirect)

I have searched quite a bit on making my blog (wordpress) mobile friendly, but every place I come across are the sites like Mofuse, which I don't really need.

What I simply want is this...

1. User hits blog.
2. User gets redirected to either m.domain.com or domain.com/m/
3. User then sees my custom mobile friendly wordpress theme.

What's the best way to go about this?  I can set my .htaccess to redirect people to either new folder, but right now the only way I can think is basically installing wordpress on the /m/ subfolder, linking to the same database and basically having two sites that way.

Or is there simple plugin that does the redirect for me, and all I have to do is create my custom theme and it will handle the rest?

Thanks

Comment: Not a duplicate. While similar, this is trying to find out how to make a subdomain for wordpress using two different themes but the same data

Comment: The basic premise of both questions is exactly the same: You want to know the best way for detecting that a site visitor is using a mobile browser and redirecting them to another page. You could have simply updated the previous question with new information about how exactly you envisioned that happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the WPTouch plugin... I use it for all my sites. But if you want a custom integration you might try iWebKit or something similar and redirect to mobile site.

WPTouch : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/

iWebKit : http://snippetspace.com/projects

Or you could setup site as multi-site and have one subdomain with domain.com/m or m.domain.com
If you have different functionality for each site.

The last two options would require a custom mobile theme. So in my opinion I would go with WPTouch.

Tom