# Detecting Device Type in a web application

Tags: java, javascript, websphere-portal

We have a Java based application where in we want to detect the device type(mobile or desktop) for the device that is sending the request.

How is it possible?

Comment: See duplicate question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent

Comment: The concept is exactly the same.  You check the user-agent.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You'll have to read the `User-Agent` header from the request and decide on that.

In vanilla servlet apps, a crude way of doing it is:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  if(request.getHeader("User-Agent").contains("Mobi")) {
    //you're in mobile land
  } else {
    //nope, this is probably a desktop
  }
}
```

Comment: Latest and better way on Mozilla site - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

Comment: Another, exhaustive, way - https://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/source/browse/Java/UAgentInfo.java

Comment: Another good library is bitwalker useragentutils: https://github.com/HaraldWalker/user-agent-utils which provides enums for BrowserType, DeviceType, OperatingSystem, Manufacturer, Version.  It can be installed via Maven, and (perhaps most importantly) is maintained.

Comment: As per Mozilla: "In summary, we recommend looking for the string “Mobi” anywhere in the User Agent to detect a mobile device."  Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

Comment: This is not working for me and I am always getting `fasle`. any idea?

Answer (score 15):

You can get device information by parsing http header

```
String browserType = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

You should parse browserType  to get device type

This may help

```
  public String  getBrowserInfo( String Information )
  {
    String browsername = "";
    String browserversion = "";
    String browser = Information;
    if (browser.contains("MSIE"))
    {
      String subsString = browser.substring(browser.indexOf("MSIE"));
      String info[] = (subsString.split(";")[0]).split(" ");
      browsername = info[0];
      browserversion = info[1];
    } else if (browser.contains("Firefox"))
    {

      String subsString = browser.substring(browser.indexOf("Firefox"));
      String info[] = (subsString.split(" ")[0]).split("/");
      browsername = info[0];
      browserversion = info[1];
    } else if (browser.contains("Chrome"))
    {

      String subsString = browser.substring(browser.indexOf("Chrome"));
      String info[] = (subsString.split(" ")[0]).split("/");
      browsername = info[0];
      browserversion = info[1];
    } else if (browser.contains("Opera"))
    {

      String subsString = browser.substring(browser.indexOf("Opera"));
      String info[] = (subsString.split(" ")[0]).split("/");
      browsername = info[0];
      browserversion = info[1];
    } else if (browser.contains("Safari"))
    {

      String subsString = browser.substring(browser.indexOf("Safari"));
      String info[] = (subsString.split(" ")[0]).split("/");
      browsername = info[0];
      browserversion = info[1];
    }
    return browsername + "-" + browserversion;
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide me more information on this. I tried to go through the data that Http Header provides but did not find the required data.

Comment: can someone fake the `User-Agent` when sending request to server? say they hit `curl` command but fake that it is coming from `Mobile`?

Comment: @daydreamer It is possible to change or "fake" what your web browser sends as its user agent. Some mobile web browsers will let you change what the browser identifies itself as (ie "Mobile Mode" or "Desktop Mode") in order to access certain websites that only allow desktop computers. If you change this setting, the user agent is what is affected.

Comment: there are plugins for both Chrome and Firefox and probably also others that allows you to write ANY useragent, even predefined "ipad" and "searchbot" useragents... not to be trusted, but good for statistics

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use [Spring Mobile](http://projects.spring.io/spring-mobile/). There are convenient classes to solve that.

```
Device currentDevice = DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(servletRequest);
if(currentDevice.isMobile()) { /* Mobile */ }
if(currentDevice.isTablet()) { /* Tablet */ }
if(currentDevice.isNormal()) { /* Desktop */ }
```

Comment: `Spring-Mobile` is `no longer supported` and has reached its `deadline`

Answer (score 5):

You could get a 3rd party software solution. There are plenty of Open Source ones out there. I've used [51Degrees.mobi's Java solution](http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/Java.aspx?CATReferrer=1765) before now (and have also worked on their open source C solution). Follow that link and hit the download button. It's relatively easy to get up and running.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this lib I think, yauaa can detect a user agent string is which device/software

https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `User-Agent` [HTTP header](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29) on the `HttpServletRequest` object.

Ref: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#user-agent

Comment: I think it will be better to put it that duplicate link on comment under the question itself. Right now it suggest that your answer is the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 51Degrees has a free API on GitHub https://github.com/51Degrees/Java-Device-Detection, it is undated regularly and should be able to cover all the basic detentions that you need.

There is a tutorial how to use the API for Device Type detection here https://51degrees.com/Developers/Documentation/APIs/Java-V32/Tutorials/Web-App

There is also a free cloud version that offers the DeviceType Property (if you want more than just IsMobile) you can find the details on this on the 51Degrees website. You will need to "purchase" the free cloud through the website, but it does not ask for bank details and is completely free. You can also use JavaScript and other integration dependant on your requirements.

Disclosure: I work at 51Degrees.

Answer (score 0):

There's also http://openddr.mobi/, Open Source Device Detection for

- Java
- C#
- VB.net

based on the [W3C Device Description Repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Device_Description_Working_Group).

OpenDDR is comparable to device repositories by 51Degrees, DeviceAtlas or ScientiaMobile/WURFL, but unlike those proprietary, closed source product, it's poen source and free to use.