# Detect whether is request coming from phone or tablet or desktop using server side code java

Tags: java, android, iphone, tablet, detect

I need to detect whether a request to a website is coming from desktop or mobile or tablet and then take 3 different actions accordingly. for example if request is coming from desktop , i take action 1, if request is coming from mobile , i take action 2 and if request comes from tablet then i take action 3.

I need to do this on server side using java.

Thanks.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: We use Jboss server and i need to do this in Java.

Comment: thanks everyone. any example would be greatly appreciated as i have not done this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use:

```
request.getHeader("User-agent");
```

With the returned value you can detect the browser, OS and device used by client.

You should test the returned values from different supported devices. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) can help you in understanding `User-agent` header

Comment: Thanks. do you have any example i can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Detecting Device Type in a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515161/detecting-device-type-in-a-web-application)

You rely on the User-Agent string to detect this. Some trial and error may be expected...there exists quite a few libraries to help with stuff like this by now, but a quick google didn't give me anything for java...you may have more luck searching than me.
A different approach I've seen used quite a bit is having something in front (web cache/load balancer/web server) set an HTTP header based on the User-String. This is effectively just implementing the feature somewhere else, but it makes for ease and re usability in your (and others'?) code.

Comment: Can someone please help me with an example or point me to a free java library that i can use?

Comment: The accepted answer in the thread I posted contains a working code example that will help you distinguish between desktop users and mobile users - should get you going! You may have to become familiar with typical User-Agent strings from at least some device types - the example simply checks whether the User-Agent contains 'Mobile', and 'Tablet' is not a widely used User-Agent keyword. That said, an Android device that is not *Mobile* is typically a tablet...

Comment: I've heard good words about WURFL before, but it's not really free: http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/
There is Apache Mobile Filter, which sets some variable for you...but then you need Apache HTTPd in front.
I also found a java class here: https://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/source/browse/Java/UAgentInfo.java