# Servlet: How to handle two responses in doPost, for two different clients?

Tags: servlets

I have a servlet, where i have doPost method implemented. I have two clients, one is mobile client and another is html web page client. I want to have two conditions under this doPost for responding two different responses for these two clients. For ex: When mobile client is calling this servlet, i will return just "Success" message, when a html web page is calling this servlet, i have to return an image. 
How do we handle two return responses based on the two client requests in servlet? I want to know the best practice and standard way of doing it. Please advise!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String type = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

More help : [Detecting Device Type in a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515161/detecting-device-type-in-a-web-application)

Comment: When this condition if(request.getHeader("User-Agent").indexOf("Mobile") != -1)  has been placed in my doPost code, its not executed in when mobile client is requesting this doPost. What could be the reason? When i print this string, it is printing like "device type: ScreenSharing/1.0 CFNetwork/548.0.3 Darwin/10.8.0' . May be i need to add header in mobile client code as well?

Comment: I added userAgent in mobile client, it worked well, thank you Jayesh!