# Faking User-Agent when sending request to server?

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, http, curl

I am reading [Detecting Device Type in a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515161/detecting-device-type-in-a-web-application) and just got curious if it would be possible to `client` to fake the `User-Agent` when sending the request?

**Question(s)**
- user sends request via `curl` command but fakes it to look as if request is coming from `Mobile` on the server? is it possible?
- Can server detect it?
- Can server prevent it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and easy. All you have to do is set the user-agent header string. I've seen a browser that allowed you to set it (don't remember which one). On the server it is very hard to know. A lot of bots pretend to be a browser so they don't get filtered out.