# How to get mobile device information through java?

Tags: java

How to get mobile-device information through java or java script ?
I need to know whenever a customer from mobile phone enters into my Website

Comment: The simplest way to do it, is look at the user agent string of the webbrowser which sends the request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the `User-Agent` header from the request.

See more on : [Detecting Device Type in a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515161/detecting-device-type-in-a-web-application)