# How to detect only the native Android browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, jquery-mobile

it's easy to detect the Android device, but I am having trouble detecting ONLY the Android native browser. Problem is the Dolphin browser has an almost identical user-agent string, and I'd like a way to know if they are using the native browser or not..

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

Comment: I don't think so? that's a general strategy. This for JUST the native browser on Android 2.X, 3.X, 4.X

Comment: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html You should be able to catch the user agent, maybe the distro as well. But as with Android this looks to be easily configurable

Comment: thanks for the link, its an interesting read but I don't think it helps me. There's stuff in there about Dolphin but it's not going to be accurate enough to help. It's a shame, I think there is no user-agent methodology to identify between Dolphin on Android 2.x and Android 2.x native. The only way I can now think of, is that Dolphin's header is effectively twice as tall as the natives so could figure that out.

Comment: you could use target-dpi media queries that only android supports, but they have been deprecated so that may not be optimal for future versions

Comment: Why are you trying to see if they are using that particular browser?  Is it something you can feature test?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403766/how-to-detect-the-stock-android-browser

Comment: Btw Dolphin browser is a webview of the stock/native browser

Answer (score 19):

you simply need to test a few parts of the user agent string in order to make sure you have the default android browser:

```
var nua = navigator.userAgent;
var is_android = (nua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 && nua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1);
```

you can use the following to ensure that you do not match chrome within android, although on a lot of devices now, chrome is being used as the default browser.

```
var nua = navigator.userAgent;
var is_android = ((nua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 && nua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1) && !(nua.indexOf('Chrome') > -1));
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to protect against case sensitivity, you can use the following:

```
var nua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_android = ((nua.indexOf('mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('android ') > -1 && nua.indexOf('applewebkit') > -1) && !(nua.indexOf('chrome') > -1));
```

Comment: This will return true even for Chrome browser in Android?

Comment: chrome is the default browser once you get to 4.1

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 running android 4.1.2 and the default browser is the android browser (not chrome).

Comment: sometimes useragent returns AppleWebkit (lowercase on kit) and this fails: ua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1. Probably best to do a regex instead of indexOf.

Comment: This will work with regex
`var nua = navigator.userAgent;`   
`var is_android = ((nua.match(/Mozilla\/5\.0/gi) !== null && nua.match(/Android/gi) !== null && nua.match(/AppleWebKit/gi) !== null) && (nua.match(/Chrome/gi) !== null));`
PS How to make new line? Two spaces doesn't work :/

Comment: since we are looking for particular, unchanging strings, using match is going to be quite a but slower than indexOf. Also, you cant do new lines in comments.

Comment: this did not detect the default android browser for Samsung Galaxy S5 (4.4.2)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are searching for this:

Android native browser not updated above version 534.30 so you can filter to the version and 
Android UA string combination (above we can presume its a Chrome browser)

**Here's my sample JavaScript code:**

*(If you need specific styling I would add a class to the body with the following JS snippet)*

```
var defectAndroid = $window.navigator && $window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('534.30') > 0 && $window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/android/);

if (defectAndroid) {
   // sample code specific for your Android Stock browser
}
```

*(Some Android devices reporting 'android' that's why we need the lower case conversation)*

Comment: what if the version is 533.1 like in Android GingerBread?  This would fail though.

Comment: Meanwhile I found this _there is no clear answer for this_

Check this out:
http://slides.com/html5test/the-android-browser#/

Comment: @PeterM, Thanks for the link to those slides, you just ruined my day ;)

Answer (score 2):

On a Galaxy S3, I found that both Chrome and the native browser had 'AppleWebkit' so I took that piece out of my conditional statement. I also added Version as that only appears in the native browser is seems. It works for me as

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var isAndroidNative = ((ua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1) && (ua.indexOf('Android') > -1) && !(ua.indexOf('Chrome') > -1) && (ua.indexOf('Version') > -1))
```

Comment: YES - this is the only actually correct answer. All of the others assume Chrome is not mentioned in the UA - which is not true.

Comment: Unfortunately it did'nt work on Samsung S5 Mini Android 4.4.2 because there was "Chrome" in the user agent string when using the Android Default Browser...

Comment: ...and on Samsung Galaxy Note S3 there is no "Version" string

Answer (score -7):

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    // Do something!
    // Redirect to Android-site?
    window.location = 'http://android.davidwalsh.name';
}
```

Comment: This just detects Android in general, not differences between different browsers available on Android (which was what the original question was looking for).

Answer (score -11):

You can do this with Javascript and the useragent feature. What u need to do is to make 2 If-requests:

**First you detect the device type:**

```
If android, ios, mobile, ipad, iphone 
   Take this setting
```

Now you make as much as u need if-requests or a case-request to detect the type of browser

```
If chrome, firefox, safari and so on
   Take this setting
```

Thats it in the theory :)