# if Android Device and not google chrome (conditional)

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, android-internet

Anyway to write a conditional; *ONLY* if Android Device and not Google Chrome then do something.

So, detect if Android (easy via below) but do something based on if Android **and** NOT google chrome; for instance do something for all Android users that are not using google chrome.

Any ideas if possible to add such a condition in similar format as below? **(this works for detecting Android, I need to add condition for if Android and not Chrome > do something)**

```
// var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
// var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
// if(isAndroid) {
//  alert("Android!");
// }
```

And I found you can detect chrome with something like the below (no way to combine them?)

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

Comment: why you tagged php ?

Comment: because i'm open to a PHP solution @DeepKakkar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24935123/2025923 might help