# Detect default android browser by Wurfl

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-agent, wurfl

I want to detect default browser of android inside my MVC controller.
I have mobile detection right now:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (WurflHelper.Instance.IsMobile(Request.UserAgent))
    {
        return View("MobileView");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

How can i detect android default browser (not chrome). I need UserAgent parameters matches for this detection.
Thanks for advice.

--------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------

i found this solution for client (javascript) : [How to detect the stock Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403766/how-to-detect-the-stock-android-browser). I need same solution for asp.net MVC

Comment: Hi. What the regex? :)

Comment: Regex based solutions don't accurately detect different device types. Android is also used in Netbook devices, TVs and set top boxes. 51Degrees (my company) provide a NuGet package that enhances the Request.Browser.IsMobile values returned by the default .NET deployment to be more accurate and address this problem. You'd use Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice to determine if the request is from a mobile. Other properties for browser name and version are also updated. The packages are available at https://51degrees.com/support/documentation/net/distributions

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you are already using WURFL to detect the device.  You could simply use the `mobile_browser` or `advertised_mobile_browser` capability to determine the browser of the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `Request.Browser` to get the browser info. Below is an example

```
var moo = Request.Browser;
var Name =  moo.Browser;
var Version =  moo.Version; 
var Major_Version = moo.MajorVersion;
var Minor_Version =  moo.MinorVersion;
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for reply. I need regex for detection. I updated my question. thanks