# How to display Shopify store only for Android users

Tags: javascript, android, shopify, liquid, user-agent

I have a shopify store and I want to only show to the people coming from android devices. For this purpose I am trying to do this via js **userAgent**. The problem is one I try to do so shopify's js and **css** files do not work correctly.

Below is my code I am trying to attempt. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
<script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("android") == -1) {
        //RUN shopify css and js files i.e: {{ 'theme.scss.css' | stylesheet_url }}
    }
    else {
        //Sorry not entertaining anything except android
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect only the native Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286355/how-to-detect-only-the-native-android-browser)

Comment: I have tried the above method and it is only detecting android but running for all devices. I want to apply the settings for only android users. When I do so the shopify theme breaks.