# Auto Mobile Site Redirect

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I just made my first jQuery mobile site.

I want to have people that view my "Full Site" with a mobile phone automatically get transferred to the "MOBILE SITE".  But also have the ability to click a link to view the Full site if they want.

I have no idea where to start.  Is there some JavaScript I could use or something?

If you want to see what the sites look like, here is the Full Site: http://www.solera-restaurant.com and the mobile site is still on my testing server: http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera_mobile/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Detecting Smartphones Using JavaScript:
http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-javascript.htm

Detecting Mobile Devices Using PHP:
http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-php.htm

iPhone & iPod Detection Using JavaScript

http://davidwalsh.name/detect-iphone

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
   if (document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == -1) window.location = "http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera_mobile/";
}
```

The PHP

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod'))
{
  header('Location: http://yoursite.com/iphone');
  exit();
}
```

You can get the javascript here: https://github.com/sebarmeli/JS-Redirection-Mobile-Site

Documentation here: http://blog.sebarmeli.com/2010/11/02/how-to-redirect-your-site-to-a-mobile-version-through-javascript/

### Here is one more mobile detection Javascript: https://github.com/miohtama/detectmobile.js

Make a javascript file and paste this code:

```
(function(a,b){if(/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))window.location=b})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera_mobile/');
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to bed now but I browsed over this info and I am pretty sure this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The code examples ignore many mobile users, such as Android and WebOS users. How come only iDevices are considered mobile browsers?

Comment: please check the script i have posted just a min ago.

Comment: The one you posted,  http://blog.sebarmeli.com..... , seems to work great! I still need to test on an iPhone though. Thanks!  Is the newer one you posted better?

Answer (score 23):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (screen.width <= 720) {
        window.location = "mobile/index.php";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Smart and elegant solution. Kudos :)

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 6):

For those of you looking for a serverside solution since that is way more efficient check this link I just found, which is a quite comprehensive list of user agents you can check to redirect on : http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

For those of you that don't know the user agent is part of the header of the request and describes the client software that oriniganated the request. Basicly its a string that you can use to identify which device requested your web page.

Comment: +1 for explaining the user agent string and giving a reference that includes scripts to parse it in many different languages.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [Device Atlas](http://deviceatlas.com/) to pick up if it is a mobile device and then send the appropriate version of the page.

There are other hacks you can do to look at the devices user agent too.

Comment: what is device user agent? This is completely new territory with me, so please get me pointed in the right direction

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways listed [here](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/), including PHP.

The jQuery one sets the variable `jQuery.browser.mobile`:

```
/**
 * jQuery.browser.mobile (http://detectmobilebrowser.com/)
 *
 * jQuery.browser.mobile will be true if the browser is a mobile device
 *
 **/
```

After this you can redirect with ordinary JS, like this:

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile) window.location = 'mobile_url';
```

<strike>Remember that it's not good to redirect the user on every page. Either make a separate mobile site or do it server-side (with e.g. PHP).</strike>

Comment: what do you mean redirect on every page? I have a full site and a completely separate mobile site, they will be hosted in the same folders but use completely different html/css etc..

Comment: The full site is here:
http://www.solera-restaurant.com

The mobile site is still in my testing hosting:
http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera_mobile/

Comment: I meant that if you want to have different HTML/CSS in the same url for different browsers, redirecting wouldn't be a choice. In this case, however, it doesn't matter, as your normal and mobile sites are in different urls.