# Mobile redirect and back to desktop using cookie?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, mobile, cookies

I have a question.
For my Joomla site I made two different templates.
One template a desktop version and the other one is for mobile use.

Both templates working fine, the desktop is the default template.

But i like to have a mobile recognition and redirect script, that redirects mobile users to the url www.domain.nl/mobiel (this url has got the mobile template)

Now i have a php code implemented into the default (desktop template). This code redictects the mobile user to this url. The script works fine.

And on the mobile page i have a url that correctly links back to the homepage in desktopmode "http://www.domain.nl/?mode=desktop"

**But the issue is that: when the mobile user is in desktop-mode and clicks on a menuitem they automaticly redirects to the mobile page. So i think the possibility is an cookie or something?**

```
    <?php
function is_mobiel(){
$regex_match="/(nokia|iphone|android|motorola|^mot\-|softbank|foma|docomo|kddi|up\.browser|up\.link|";
$regex_match.="htc|dopod|blazer|netfront|helio|hosin|huawei|novarra|CoolPad|webos|techfaith|palmsource|";
$regex_match.="blackberry|alcatel|amoi|ktouch|nexian|samsung|^sam\-|s[cg]h|^lge|ericsson|philips|sagem|wellcom|bunjalloo|maui|";    
$regex_match.="symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|iemobiel|^spice|^bird|^zte\-|longcos|pantech|gionee|^sie\-|portalmmm|";
$regex_match.="jig\s browser|hiptop|^ucweb|^benq|haier|^lct|opera\s*mobi|opera\*mini|320x320|240x320|176x220";
$regex_match.=")/i";        
return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE']) or preg_match($regex_match, strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
}
switch($_GET['mode'])
{
case 'mobiel':
$mode = "mobiel";
break;
case 'desktop':
$mode = "desktop";
break;
default:
$mode = is_mobiel() ? "mobiel" : "desktop";
break;
}
if ($mode == "mobiel")
{
header ("Location: http://www.domain.nl/mobiel?m");
return;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, this seems like the same question like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511526/auto-mobile-site-redirect

Answer (score 0):

For detecting whether http request coming from mobile or not. For that you can check also by following way and do as per requirements.

Try like this way:

```
  $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))){
header ("Location: http://www.domain.nl/mobiel?m");
}
else
{
      //for desktop do something 
}
```

Comment: My redirection scripts is working, and the switch back to to desktop-mode works, but when the user clicks on a menuitem (the template/script will run again) and the user wille been redirectend back to http://www.domain.nl/mobiel?m instead of going to the menuitem in desktop-mode....

Comment: I think i foun a great solution (with cookie) https://github.com/miohtama/detectmobile.js