# On Submit Add Entered E-Mail To E-Mail Subscribers List

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This question is more than likely a duplicate however I cannot find this question already on StackOverflow.

### HTML Snippet

```
<!-- newsletter widget -->
<div class="widget-container newsletterBox">
    <div class="inner">
        <h3>Newsletter</h3>
        <form method="get" action="#">
            <input type="text" value="" name="email" class="inputField" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="btn-arrow">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/ newsletter widget -->
```

A basic input field with a submit button resides on my html page.

How do I safely add their e-mail to the likes of a .txt file on my server without the person being able to enter code to hack my website?

Is it possible to keep my page .html and not have to use PHP?

Comment: Just a note: that's a pretty bad way of redirecting mobile users. Try something like [this](http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/detecting-and-redirecting-mobile-users/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9511526/1757964)

Comment: Could you please clarify the question?  Add some context from these comments and explain what you want to happen.

Comment: Seems to now be working, I'm going to edit question now, can you please all remove comments?