# facebook app visibility on mobile devices

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, mobile

I noticied some apps (like pinterest) are visible on mobile device (android or iphone facebook app) and redirect to the mobile version of facebook

Do u know what I have to change in my apps settings to make my app visible on mobile apps ?

Comment: This admin question is better suited for the http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/ group rather than this technical programming forum.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you would detect the User Agent or device, and redirect. See here: [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)