# HTTP request made by a mobile device

Tags: http, mobile-website, user-agent

How can I detect whether an HTTP request has been made by a mobile device or by a desktop web browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

Answer (score 0):

If you control the request, then you can add info to it as needed, e.g. as fields in a POST or GET. Otherwise, you can peek at the [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string of the request.

Coming from iOS, the User-Agent string will include the app name and version, as well as the version of CoreFoundation used to build the request. Coming from Android devices it depends on how the programmer of the app set things up, but it usually will tell you it was an Apache/Java client. Coming from Firefox, it will tell you 'Mozilla', etc.

You also have to understand that the programmer of the client can spoof this if he wants, and there's not much you can do about it.