# How detect user came from Web or from Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

User can came from web or from devise (Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod) How correctly detect it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing incoming header 'User-Agent'
in php it is `apache_request_headers()`
It will return a key-value pair array
For example:

```
Array
(
  [Host] => www.testing.local
  [Connection] => keep-alive
  [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.206.1 Safari/532.0
  [Cache-Control] => max-age=0
  [Accept] => application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
  [Accept-Encoding] => gzip,deflate,sdch
  [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.8
  [Accept-Charset] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
)
```

Comment: http://user-agents.my-addr.com/user_agent_request/user_agent_examples-and-user_agent_types.php

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
if request.user_agent.include?("iPhone") || request.user_agent.include?("Android")
```

I use this to render a mobile layout in several of my apps.