# How to direct to mobile site/template?

Tags: php, mobile, joomla, joomla2.5

I would like to know how to display a template for mobile users, and a template for desktop users on a j2.5 site? Is this possible without using a sub domain?

If not, then what is the most efficient way to detect a mobile user, and display an alternative .css file only (as opposed to a different template)?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent

Comment: There are thousands upon thousands of pages out on the web that cover every aspect of this topic. As a word of caution, the methods for sniffing browsers are generally the subject of long debates over accuracy, reliability, scalability, etc

Comment: Hi, yes I am aware of the many posts about mobile detection in general, however I am asking above then switching the template in joomla, and if this isn't possible without using a sub domain, then use an alternative .css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the users browser (including mobile) via the browsers User Agent. In PHP this is available through

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

which will display a string like

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.165 Safari/535.19
```

That's my current user agent using Chrome on a MacBook.

You can run a regex match against this string to match to known mobile browsers and redirect the to a mobile version of the site. Most websites use a `m.` or `mobile.` subdomain.