# Ask user if they want to see the mobile version of the page, redirect accordingly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, redirect, mobile

I just need to find out how to detect if the user is on a mobile device, and ask them if they want to see the mobile instead of the regular site, and redirect accordingly. Is there a non-PHP solution? Or a WP plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this previous Questions:

Detect Mobile using Jquery & PHP:

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery)

[Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

Or Using this stuff to check if user using mobile device you can show dialog box for redirect it:

http://barisaydinoglu.github.com/Detectizr/

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays Responsive Design ([here](http://netuncovered.com/2011/05/reactive-web-design/) and [here](http://www.saraproft.net/blog/?p=4502)) is the prefered path to take.
Though not a direct answer to you question but this would be the path I'd take instead.

**Edit:**
If you want to do this in Javascript/jQuery you can ulitize [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) for feature detection instead of fixed browser detection.

If you want strict browser detection you can check the [UserAgent](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/) and take appropriate action.

Comment: I'd do this but the client specifically requested this.