# How do i detect mobile devices for my website

Tags: jquery, mobile, detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

Ok so i made this mobile version for my website which is at mobile.mysite.com but how do i get it so that when users go to mysite.com from any mobile device (ipads,ipods,cellphones, etc....) that it goes to mobile.mysite.com

Comment: have you tried searching? this is a pretty common question.. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1005153/944681)

Comment: I don't think that there was thorough research of the topic before asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to determine if the client has touch events then redirecting to mobile.mysite.com

You could also detect the resolution of the device, but this is becoming less helpful since phones now have HD resolution screens.

If you're using php consider using this [script](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)

Answer (score 0):

You can go the route of using CSS3 media queries and responsive design or you can can use some sort of JavaScript library like device.js to check which phone the user is using and which features it has available.