# How can I detect if a browser is mobile and switch between normal and mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, html5boilerplate

I assume it involves the view-port somehow, but I'm not good at mobile. I'd like to re-size my font and move my elements around.

I see that HTML 5 Boilerplate comes in a mobile form, how and when would I switch to that?

Comment: I decided my question was not well thought out and decided to switch to the mobile BP for everything was css media queries. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may parse the user agent to determine the mobile platform (e.g., iPhone, iPad, iPod, Android, Opera, Android, BlackBerry, hpwOS, Windows PhoneOS, etc.).

And it is better to use a @media query in CSS to take advantage of the screen dimensions.

For reference:

- https://mislav.net/2010/04/targeted-css/
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need to change.

To change Boilerplate to Boilerplate Mobile you could have a server-side condition and render a completely different page. If you are using some kind of dynamic framework or have direct access to the server you can [check for User-Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

[Here](https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2010/using-mobile-specific-html-css-and-javascript-mobile-web-part-5/) is an article that explains how to use mobile-specific JS, CSS and HTML. Hope it helps.