# Alert when user opens website op mobile

Tags: mobile, web, notifications, alert

How to show an alert to an user when he / she opens my website on a mobile phone?

I want to know this as I want to notify the user how to set the website application on his / hers mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

There are many scripts available to do this for you.  YOu would have to check it on the server side and relay this information to your front end to alert the user.

this post might be of help.
[Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)