# best way to redirect to mobile site in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, redirect, mobile

I'm looking for a solution to redirect users to our mobile version of site if they open our website in their mobile and tablet devices. We'd also like to give user the option to go to our public website if they wish to. both are .NET websites.

I had a quick look around and noticed there are javascript detection libraries, but I want to use something at the server side, like 51 degrees

Would you help us achieving that?

Cheers.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using and is it web forms or MVC?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using a media query? You could use it to detect the window size and apply the appropriate CSS.

Comment: But I dont want to detect screen size. I want it so that it just detect mobile and pc version. I have limited knowledge there.

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent