# Detect UserAgent is not from Mobile

Tags: c#, user-agent, handhelddevice

**Condition**
Hi currently I have a function to detect if the client request is from  mobile or not.
The function is as below.

```
public bool IsHandheld()
        {
            bool status = false;

            string strUserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower();
            if (strUserAgent != null)
            {
                if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true || strUserAgent.Contains("iphone") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("blackberry") || strUserAgent.Contains("mobile") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("windows ce") || strUserAgent.Contains("opera mini") ||
                    strUserAgent.Contains("palm"))
                {
                    status = true;
                }
            }
            return status;
        }
```

**Problem:**
This is not enough to detect the handheld device so
I got a list of string over internet to compare if it is contained in Userstring

```
  new string[] { "blackberry" ,"iphone","mobile","windows ce","opera mini",
                    "palm","symbianos", "ipad", "symbianos", "ipod", "blackberry",
                    "sonyericsson", "android", "samsung", "nokia", "wap", "motor"
                });
```

If the devices  went on incresaing then this list would be long

I want to reverse the condition. I want to detect if the request is from PC or laptop not from handheld device.
Is there any way to do so?
Or am I thinking in the wrong way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

Comment: @Thilo  i want to detect the type of device either PC/Laptop not the browser

Comment: I think that's exactly what that other question is about: decide if the browser visiting you is a mobile browser or a desktop browser.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks I was misunderstood. Thanks for the link It helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

[This is nice Blog i think this will help you.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx)

It recommends using `request.Browser.IsMobileDevice`