# meta viewport tag script not working

Tags: javascript, html, viewport

I'm trying to use the solution provided here [Meta viewport ONLY for phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134386/meta-viewport-only-for-phones) to generate a meta viewport tag on phones only, I'm adding the script in the head section of the document but it's not being generated, and I'm getting a "SyntaxError: Expected token ')' error on the console.

Here's the script I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
            document.write('<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=no'>');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix this one line:

```
document.write("<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=no'>");
```

You need to swap the opening and closing `'` for `"`, otherwise the string can't be properly parsed.

Complete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
            document.write("<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=no'>");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now it's deleting the entire document html... on loading the page the content flashes for a split second, then disappears and all I get is a blank page (the actual HTML is empty in the web inspector)

Comment: instead of `document.write`, I'd suggest using a more reliable approach such as is given in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588628/can-i-change-the-viewport-meta-tag-in-mobile-safari-on-the-fly

Comment: Perfect, using `('head').append` instead of `document.write` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

To detect mobile browsers try this : http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

```
(function(a){
    if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)
        || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))
    document.write("<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=no'>");
})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use double brackets `"` and then single brackets inside `'`

or

you need to escape second set of brackets like this `\'`

so you code will become

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
            document.write("<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=no'>");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need to echo this script via PHP

```
<?php echo'
<script type="text/javascript">
  var viewPortTag=document.createElement("meta");
  viewPortTag.id="viewport";
  viewPortTag.name = "viewport";
  viewPortTag.content = "width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; 
  user-scalable=0;";
  window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);
</script>';
?>
```