# Bootstrap table goes over screen edge on smartphone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making my first laravel project using bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/) and I bumped into a problem with mobile devices.

I am using a bootstrap4 basic table, (not using `responsive` property is not the problem) and using `small` property does not help either.

When the website is loaded, it shows as in **picture 1**. Now to see whole table, I need to slide left, as in **picture 2** or zoom out as in **picture 3**.

Can I force my site to zoom out as shown in **pic 3** when loaded? Or make the table fit into the page like in **picture 1**, since my `NAV` wont scale?
I need whole table to be visible right away, even if not readable and the user would zoom it himself.

I tried wrapping only the table in `<div class="container"></div>` and in `.container-fluid` too
but neither would help.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you.

[link to pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynvz8.jpg)
[image]

code:

```
<div class="container">
      <h1>List</h1>
      <div class="row">
            <div class="dropdown">
                  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        {{ request('aec') ? $aecs->find(request('aec'))->name : '' }}
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('ae.index') }}">Všetky</a>
                        @foreach ($aecs as $aec)
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('ae.index', ['aec' => $aec]) }}">{{ $aec->name }}</a>
                        @endforeach
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
      <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                  <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center align-middle">ID</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center align-middle">Typ</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center align-middle">Názov</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center align-middle">Skratka</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center align-middle">Pseudo ID</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="text-center align-middle">Fotografia</th>
                  </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                  @forelse ($aes as $ae)
                  <tr>
                        <th scope="row" class="text-center align-middle">
                              <a href="{{ $ae->path() }}">
                                    {{ $ae->AECategory->id . "." . $ae->id }}
                              </a>
                        </th>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ $ae->AECategory->name }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle"><a href="{{ $ae->path() }}">{{ $ae->name }}</a></td>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ $ae ->nickname }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle">{{ $ae->pseudo_id }}</td>
                        <td class="text-center align-middle">
                              <div class="gallery">
                                    <a data-fancybox="gallery"
                                          href="{{ $ae->image ? asset($ae->image->path) : '' }}">
                                          <img
                                          src="{{ $ae->image ? asset($ae->image->path025) : '' }}"
                                          class="img-fluid img"
                                          width="250"
                                          height="250"
                                          alt=""
                                          >
                                    </a>
                              </div>
                        </td>
                  </tr>
                  @empty

                  @endforelse
            </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`viewport` `meta` tag](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) with `initial-scale` attribute. Give the initial-scale a value of `0.5` zoom. The page will be zoomed with a value given in the initial-scale attribute. Please note that this is only applicable for the initial load of the page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=.5" />
```

[This page](https://css-tricks.com/best-way-programmatically-zoom-web-application/) will also give you more insights on page zoom.

Comment: This solution looks great, but how do I make it so it scales to 50% only for smartphones and make it stay 100% on computer's browsers?

Comment: @narrei we can target only on mobile devices, there are multiple ways to do this, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134386/meta-viewport-only-for-phones

Answer (score 0):

wrap your html with a container, I don't know what you're calling your classes, since you didn't post it making it very difficult to help.

```
/*in css*/
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px){

.yourclasshere tagshere{
    width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

here is an example of a class I have called wrapper and the code from css.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px){
    .wrapper{
        width: calc(100% - 32px);
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Hope it helps, I'm new. Startet with code this week

So this should work for you if you add it to your css stylesheet.

```
/*whenever the screen size is less than 1000 pixels wide it runs the code inside*/
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px){
    .container{
/*sets the container width to 100% - 32 pixels, so you get 16pixel gap on both sides of the container*/
        width: calc(100% - 32px);
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

here is a great tutorial on doing it https://youtu.be/kbLfWKGVsMQ he also has other stuff, quite a nice channel

Comment: Should work if you put this into your css stylesheet

Comment: Did you try this? because it does exactly what you're asking for keeping everything on screen regardless of what device you're viewing it on.