# JavaScript disabled: how to show different messages for mobile and desktop.

Tags: javascript, noscript

I need to display different messages for desktop and mobile web sites when JavaScript is disabled.

Currently I have

```
<noscript>  
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=/error.html" />
</noscript>
```

and i need code that would do (i use pseudocode)

```
<noscript>
    if desktop
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=/error.html" />
    if mobile
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=/mobile-error.html" />
</noscript>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is is possible to responsively design `error.html` so that it will look good on all devices?

Comment: No, it needs to display different content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any server backend to your website? You could try and do mobile browser detection based off of the user-agent received from the connecting browser.

See [this stackoverflow post about using the user agent to detect mobile.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)