# JSP Forwarding in Mobile dosn't work

Tags: jsp

I have created application in two versions. For personal and mobile browsers.

Simply, client logins on page login.jsp. Then authorization took place in the `servlet.java( auto.jsp)`. IF authorization was correct, the client were moving on page dane.jsp, otherwise were moving him on page login.jsp.

Unfortunately, forwarding in first and second version, dosen't work in 100%.
After good authorization, client see content of page dane.jsp but he still was on page auto.jsp. For personal browser I have changed method from `request.getRequestDispatcher("dane.jsp").forward (request, response);` to `response.sendRedirect("dane.jsp");` and it worked. But I don't have idea for mobile edition.

will sb save me?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  When posting questions about your code, please share what you've written so that we can see what may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check user-agent type and redirect accordingly by having if..else.. loop on serverside before serving jsp page.

Pls check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent) for more information.

Comment: I did it. i used script form this page : http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/. In mobile version, after successful login user see content of dane.jsp but the adddress bar still shows ...auto.jsp and not dane.jsp

Comment: instead of requestDispatcher, use response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/dane.jsp");

Comment: @user3557849: sorry no idea for that. It worked for me though. Try giving absolute path instead of "request.getContextPath()"