# How to load content of website as mobile web browser in my winform web browser C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have made a web browser in C#, but i want an option like **use as a mobile browser**, like which contents of websites will load as mobile browser like if at that moment user browses *www.facebook.com* it will automatically go to *m.facebook.com* such as our mobile phone browsers does.

I can make this by replacing **www** to **m** by **String Changing** but some other sites like **blogspot** sites has two different views for mobile and web in one domain of *{myblog}.blogspot.com*

So for these cases, **is it possible** to load contents as mobile browser in my winform web browser **{im using C#}**

EDIT: I meant something like User Agent

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)?

Comment: yeah, i  dont want to detect mobile browser, because user will use this windows app, but contents will load as mobile page. my app is not a mobile application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
webBrowser.Navigate("http://localhost/run.php", null, null,
                string.Format("User-Agent: {0}", "Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/9 (Compatible; MSIE:9.0; iPhone; BlackBerry9700; AppleWebKit/24.746; U; en) Presto/2.5.25 Version/10.54"));
```